# How to import items from an CSV file using ‘Galaxy’?

Tags: axapta, x++

How can I import items from an CSV-file using the ‘Galaxy’ tool in AXAPTA X++?

Galaxy is a tool developed by Columbus IT.

Comment: If you find the answer useful, then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more application usage than programming related.

But basically you need to define a "structure":

[image: Structure]

Use a format:

[image]

Specify a "Line structure" defining the fields:

[image]

Then setup a flow for import using that structure:

[image]